# hair particles emit from faces outside vertex group

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

trying some basic hair particles for my model but whenver i render hair emits from the entire face rather than the vertex grp assigned  even tho it is correct in the viewport.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to also assign the vertex group for some hair particle system parameters;

In Particle Settings / Hair settings, open tab "Vertex Groups" and assign your vertex group for example for Density and Length.

[image]

Comment: i have done that only the density and it looks like that in the view pot buts abandons the grp when rendering